# Ical IOS - Add multiple entries at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

Is it possible to add multiple calendar entries into Ical at once?

I am building a HTML5 IOS app - a large feature of which is client bookings - we'd like the clients client to be able to download all bookings at once into their ICal - I can find info for adding a single entry but not multiple - is this possible - ideally via jQuery / Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **add events to the calendar programatically with iOS**, I don't know about jQuery/Javascript. The way to achieve it with iOS would be like this.

**First:**

Add the EventKit framework and #import  to your code.

**Second:**

Create an EKEvnetStore an ask for permission in order to add events to the calendar.

**Third:**

For each event you may have in an array you need to create and EKEvent object and set the correct data and finally saved it.

Following some code as an example:

```
  EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) { return; }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = @"Event Title";
        event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
        NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
    }];
```

Comment: finally got round to implemeting this - works great and now all makes sense!  Cheers for your help!